# Databricks artifacts allow list - how to find it?

Tags: java, cloud, databricks

I am trying to install a JAVA library (com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:3.4.1_0.19.0) in the Azure Databricks cluster, but receive a message

"Jars and Maven Libraries on Shared Clusters must be on the allowlist. Failed Libraries: com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:3.4.1_0.19.0: PERMISSION_DENIED: 'com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:3.4.1_0.19.0' is not in the artifact allowlist"

Are there here to give some idea how can I find this inside the Databricks?
I tried to find it in the documentation, but not find it.

Comment: Maybe wrong - but when I googled allow list, only reference I could find was related to Databricks Cluster policy with ability to allow or deny lists...Hope it helps ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Databricks cluster with "Shared" access mode, you must add your Maven coordinates to the Unity Catalog metastore allowlist (no need for Python pypi libraries)

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/compute/compatibility#shared-access-mode-support-for-libraries-and-init-scripts

This is how a metastore admin can add artifacts to the allowlist:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/manage-privileges/allowlist